# Links No Longer Work After Wordpress Server Migration

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, wamp

I had a Wordpress server running on a windows based WAMP server and I just migrated over to my main Ubuntu Server. The first thing I did was move the database over and then the files. After pointing the Wordpress config file to the new database, the home page loaded right up!

The problem is that the nav links or any other link that is NOT the homepage loads a 404 error.

I have tried pointing my Virtualhost to the .htaccess file and then also re-saving the permalinks in wordpress.

Here is my current Virtual host file

Virtual Hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName WherehouseMKE.com

    ServerAdmin info@wherehousemke.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: WherehouseMKE.com this is your URL right ?

Comment: Links are working i have checked

Comment: "I have tried pointing my Virtualhost to the .htaccess file" ... How that?!?

Comment: @arkascha by using 
'''
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
'''

Comment: @Dhruv Yes it is working right now because I need to keep the site up. But when point the domain name to the new serve it does not work.

Comment: How does that point to a certain file?